# SciPy optimization

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I have been attempting to calibrate my model, but I am running into issues with scipy.optimize module. I have tried various scipy optimizers, but they all return the error "TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "list") to tuple". Does anyone know how to resolve this issue? Thank you for your time.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
from numba import jit, njit,float64
from scipy.optimize import fmin_slsqp


i=complex(0,1)
sigma, kappa, theta, volvol, rho = 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1
params=[sigma, kappa, theta, volvol, rho]
strikes=[4650,4655,4660,4665,4670]
maturities=[1/48,2/48,3/48,1/12,5/48]
marketPrices=[70.00,66.70,63.50,60.35,57.30,82.50,79.20,76.0,72.80,69.70,92.65,89.35,86.10,82.90,79.75,101.60,98.30,95.10,91.90,88.75,109.85,106.60,103.35,100.20,97.00]
marketPrices=np.array(marketPrices)
rates=[0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05]
St=4662
np.shape(marketPrices)





@jit
def fHeston(s, St, K, r, T, sigma, kappa, theta, volvol, rho):
    # To be used a lot
    prod = rho * sigma *i *s 
    
    # Calculate d
    d1 = (prod - kappa)**2
    d2 = (sigma**2) * (i*s + s**2)
    d = np.sqrt(d1 + d2)
    
    # Calculate g
    g1 = kappa - prod - d
    g2 = kappa - prod + d
    g = g1/g2
    
    # Calculate first exponential
    exp1 = np.exp(np.log(St) * i *s) * np.exp(i * s* r* T)
    exp2 = 1 - g * np.exp(-d *T)
    exp3 = 1- g
    mainExp1 = exp1 * np.power(exp2/ exp3, -2 * theta * kappa/(sigma **2))
    
    # Calculate second exponential
    exp4 = theta * kappa * T/(sigma **2)
    exp5 = volvol/(sigma **2)
    exp6 = (1 - np.exp(-d * T))/(1 - g * np.exp(-d * T))
    mainExp2 = np.exp((exp4 * g1) + (exp5 *g1 * exp6))
    
    return (mainExp1 * mainExp2)

@jit(forceobj=True)
def priceHestonMid(St, K, r, T, sigma, kappa, theta, volvol, rho):
    P, iterations, maxNumber = 0,1000,100
    ds = maxNumber/iterations
    
    element1 = 0.5 * (St - K * np.exp(-r * T))
    
    # Calculate the complex integral
    # Using j instead of i to avoid confusion
    for j in range(1, iterations):
        s1 = ds * (2*j + 1)/2
        s2 = s1 - i
        
        numerator1 = fHeston(s2,  St, K, r, T, sigma, kappa, theta, volvol, rho)
        numerator2 = K * fHeston(s1,  St, K, r, T, sigma, kappa, theta, volvol, rho)
        denominator = np.exp(np.log(K) * i * s1) *i *s1
        
        P = P + ds *(numerator1 - numerator2)/denominator
    
    element2 = P/np.pi
    
    return np.real((element1 + element2))


# vectorify 
def strikematurePriceHestonMid(St, W, r, Q, sigma, kappa, theta, volvol, rho):
    stuff=[]
    volsur=[]
    e=0
    p=0
    for p in range(5):
        for e in range(5):
            stuff.append(priceHestonMid(St, W[e], r, Q[p], sigma, kappa, theta, volvol, rho))
            
            #volsur[e][p]=stuff[4*p::4*p+4]
            #print(priceHestonMid(St, W[e], r, Q[p], sigma, kappa, theta, volvol, rho))
    
    volsur=np.reshape(stuff,(5,5))
    stuff=np.array(stuff)
    return stuff


def calibratorHeston(St, initialValues = [0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,-0.5], 
                              lowerBounds = [1e-2,1e-2,1e-2,1e-2,-1], 
                              upperBounds = [10,10,10,10,0]):

    objectiveFunctionHeston = ((marketPrices) - (strikematurePriceHestonMid(St, strikes,  
                                                                        rates[0], 
                                                                        maturities, 
                                                                        sigma,                         
                                                                        kappa,
                                                                        theta,
                                                                        volvol,
                                                                        rho))).sum()
        
    result=fmin_slsqp(objectiveFunctionHeston,initialValues,args=params)   
        
    return result
        
calibratorHeston(4662)
```

UPDATE:

I was able to figure out how to get it done, I am still not sure why it was not working before nonetheless I got it working with SciPy. Thank you all.

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def objectiveFunctionHeston(x,St, strikes,rates, maturities):

    objective = ((marketPrices)-(strikematurePriceHestonMid(St, strikes,  
                                                                        rates, 
                                                                       maturities, 
                                                                        sigma=x[0],                         
                                                                        kappa=x[1],
                                                                        theta=x[2],
                                                                        volvol=x[3],
                                                                        rho=x[4])))/marketPrices
    objective=np.square(np.dot(objective,objective))
    return objective

bounds=((1e-2,5),(1e-2,8),(1e-2,10),(1e-2,10),(-1,1))
res = minimize(objectiveFunctionHeston, method='SLSQP',  x0=[sigma, kappa, theta, volvol, rho],args=(St,strikes,rates[0],maturities),
                  bounds = bounds, tol=1e-20, 
                  options={"maxiter":1000})
print(res)
```

Comment: Which line gives that error? Your code is too long.

Comment: Sorry about the code being too long I don't use stackexchange often I was not aware I just wanted to ease the debugging process. the line of code  `result=fmin_slsqp(objectiveFunctionHeston,initialValues,args=params)`

Comment: try making `params` a tuple instead of a list.  Usually debugging is easiest with a **full** traceback, especially if you don't understand what's happening.

Comment: Wild guess, I think `param` is throwing that error. Your `param` is a list. For function arguments, you need to send a tuple.

Comment: I believe it is from the `objectiveFunctionHeston` it is recognizing `marketPrices` and `strikematurePriceHestonMid` as lists not arrays, which is why it says " TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "list") to tuple"

Comment: Could you check that you pasted the correct code please? The code is good it runs without any modification but it gives `TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable` here.

Comment: It is correct. I still get the error `TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "list") to tuple.`